# Add an integer to a key of an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, increment

let's say we have the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => 123456 [1] => Rothmans Blue [2] => 40 [3] => RB44 [4] => 1 )
```

I want to reprint this array, with the [4]th key having an additional +1, like so:

```
Array ( [0] => 123456 [1] => Rothmans Blue [2] => 40 [3] => RB44 [4] => 2 )
```

Then again:

```
Array ( [0] => 123456 [1] => Rothmans Blue [2] => 40 [3] => RB44 [4] => 3 )
```

**EDIT:** The solutions given below work, however, my code does not increment the 4th key:

```
$filew = 'databases/stocktakemain.csv';
$getfilecont = file_get_contents($filew);
$writes = explode(",", $getfilecont);
++$writes[4];
```

Is there an issue with this code? Does this not apply when creating arrays through explode?

Comment: Will that element always have a key of `4`? If so, `$array[4]++` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the ++ to incremente in 1 your 4th array value

```
<?php

$array[0] = 123456;
$array[1] = 'Rothmans Blue';
$array[2] = 40;
$array[3] = 'RB44';
$array[4] = 1;

echo ++$array[4] . "<br>\n";
echo ++$array[4] . "<br>\n";
echo ++$array[4] . "<br>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Hey Adrian, this solution is great though it is not working with my code... please see edit above..

Comment: All OK Adrian, I needed to trim the key:$writes[4] = trim($writes[4]);
++$writes[4];

Comment: @atomapps you need trim the 4th element?

Comment: it seems that way for my database (csv), not sure why but I guess it's fine?

Comment: try this: `key:$writes[4] = ++((int)trim($writes[4]));`. Parsing it to int should help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `end($array)` function and get the last element and then add.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code, you can put
Array[4] == Array[4] + 1;

Comment: You can also add through $array[4]++

Comment: Hi Vishok, I want to reprint the whole array with just that value updated?

Comment: seems I needed to trim the key:
$writes[4] = trim($writes[4]);
++$writes[4];

Answer (score 0):

This will print out 10 arrays with that last key being an incrementing number, change the $max to make it bigger/smaller.

```
$max = 10;

for( $i=1; $i<=$max; $i++ ) {
    print_r( array(
        123456,
        'Rothmans Blue',
        40,
        'RB44',
        $i
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't actually need to declare the key values as PHP considers the index of a value in an array to be its key.

You might try something like this if you want to print the values, then increment:

```
$myArray = array(123456, "Rothmans Blue", 40, "RB44", 1);
for ($i= 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  foreach ($myArray as $key => $value)
  {
    print $key . " : " . $value;
    if ($key == 4)
    {
      print "\n";
      $myArray[$key] += 1; // Make sure to modify the original array, not the one you passed in as it is passed by reference.
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to increment and then print, move the print statement to the bottom of the foreach loop.